# ErrorMessage while open connection to Denodo via npgsql in c#

Tags: c#, npgsql, denodo

sorry, if this is question is (to) easy for stackoverflow community.

I am trying to connect to Denodo (Version 7), via c# code.

I installed npqsql and created a connection string with:  {host} {port} {username} {passwd} {database} and the SSL-Mode as required.

(user and pwd combination was checked via Launch Pad)

For trying I use a simple select statement.

If I call Open() on my NpqsqlConnection object I get the error message {"Received unexpected backend message ParseComplete. Please file a bug."}

For beeing sure I tried to ping the host, which works fine. And if I try without SSl, the error message indicates that the SSl is required, therefor I think the correct backend is found.

Could someone give me a hint?

Thanks 
Jessi

I checked the Denodo Community, and the given examples: https://community.denodo.com/docs/html/browse/6.0/vdp/developer/access_through_an_ado.net_data_provider/access_through_an_ado.net_data_provider 
https://community.denodo.com/answers/question/details?questionId=90670000000XcbkAAC&title=How+to+execute+C%23+program+using+vdp-clients-ADO.NET

Comment: Which version of Npgsql are you using? In any case, the error seems to show a protocol issue where denodo diverges from regular PostgreSQL. Npgsql sieht include any specific sorry for denodo, assuming that it behaves like PG - someone from denodo would have to come in and help.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to mention the versions: I am using the version 4.0.6 from Npqsl in Visual Studio 2015.